# I am getting null values in my Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am playing around with an ArrayList and trying to get it to grow twice it's size every time it exceeds it's size. Here is my add method:

```
public class ArrayExpander
{
   private int size;
   private int noOfItems;
   private Object[] store;
   private final int INITIALSIZE = 2;

   public ArrayExpander()
   {
      store = new Object[INITIALSIZE];
      noOfItems = 0;
      size = INITIALSIZE;
   }

   public void add(Object obj)
   {
      growBufferIfNecessary();
      store[size++] = obj;
      /*for (int i = size - 1; i < store.length; i++)
      {
         store[i] = store[i - 1];
         store[i] = obj;
      }*/   
   }

   public String toString()
   {
      String temp = "[" + store[0];
      for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
      {
          temp = temp + "," + store[i];
      }
      temp = temp + "]";
      return temp;
   }
   private void growBufferIfNecessary()
   {
      if (size == store.length)
      {
         Object[] newStore = new Object[2 * store.length];
         for (int i = 0; i < store.length; i++) 
         { 
            newStore[i] = store[i]; 
         }      
         store = newStore;
      }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      ArrayExpander ae = new ArrayExpander();
      //System.out.println(ae);
      ae.add("a");
      ae.add("b");
      System.out.println(ae);
      ae.add("c");
      ae.add("d");  
      ae.add("e");
      ae.add("f");
      ae.add("g");
      ae.add("h");  
      System.out.println(ae);
      ae.add("i");
      System.out.println(ae);
   }
}
```

Here is my output:

```
[null,null]
[null,null,a,b]
[null,null,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]
[null,null,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]
```

I can't figure out why I am getting the null statements. The first line should be a,b and then the arraylist should double in size and be a,b,c,d. I have it set for final int INITIALSIZE = 2.
The output I am looking for is

```
[a,b]
[a,b,c,d]
[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]
[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]
```

Comment: can you share the code for growBufferIfNecessary too ! Also you need to share the entire code here we don't know what size variable is.

Comment: also it looks like you've got an array not an ArrayList from the output.

Comment: when do you initialize `size`? also, post the code where you call `add`

Comment: @La-comadreja I believe he is trying to implement `ArrayList`

Comment: I can put the entire code up but in the past when I have done that I get voted down for some reason. I was told that it was frowned upon.

Comment: you probably want to start by ensuring elements a and b are added at index 0.

Comment: @Dustin You need to post the code that is related and not the entire code. ! you need to give information on the size variable and the place from where add is called and how it is called !

Comment: why is there a loop in your add ? shouldn't it be simply `growBufferIfNecessary(); store[size++] = obj;`?

Comment: store[i] = store[i - 1];
store[i] = obj;
These lines... Some magic are behind!

Comment: I bet there is a `size = INITIAL_SIZE` somewhere

Comment: It might help to see just where/how this "output" is being produced.

Comment: Why don't you paste your entire code. If it is too big, just post the relevant. It would be helpful.

Comment: I just added the main method where the call to add is.

Comment: @Dustin we still don't know what is the size variable i think it is a class level variable. can you share the code for that too!

Comment: Yes it is a class lvl variable look up the implementation of an ArrayList and you will understand what he is trying to do.

Comment: Start by replacing the dense code with `System.arraycopy`.

Comment: You should not be incrementing size in add method you should be incrementing numOfItems

Comment: Ok, I will try that real quick!

Comment: @Dustin look at my answer and you will see what you were doing wrong.

Comment: @Dustin, you may want to consider a more specific title for this question. Something like: Trying to expand ArrayList Class, and get null values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will work for you.  size should be referring to the size of your array while noOfItems refers to the number of items in your array.  You were kind of mixing the 2 up.  I only changed a couple things in your add() and growBufferIfNecessary().

```
public class ArrayExpander
{
   private int size;
   private int noOfItems;
   private Object[] store;
   private final int INITIALSIZE = 2;

   public ArrayExpander()
   {
      store = new Object[INITIALSIZE];
      noOfItems = 0;
      size = INITIALSIZE;
   }

   public void add(Object obj)
   {
      growBufferIfNecessary();
      store[noOfItems++] = obj;
   }

   public String toString()
   {
      String temp = "[" + store[0];
      for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
      {
          temp = temp + "," + store[i];
      }
      temp = temp + "]";
      return temp;
   }
   private void growBufferIfNecessary()
   {
      if (noOfItems == size)
      {
         size = 2 * size;
         Object[] newStore = new Object[size];
         for (int i = 0; i < store.length; i++) 
         { 
            newStore[i] = store[i]; 
         }      
         store = newStore;
      }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      ArrayExpander ae = new ArrayExpander();
      //System.out.println(ae);
      ae.add("a");
      ae.add("b");
      System.out.println(ae);
      ae.add("c");
      ae.add("d");  
      ae.add("e");
      ae.add("f");
      ae.add("g");
      ae.add("h");  
      System.out.println(ae);
      ae.add("i");
      System.out.println(ae);
   }
}
```

Try this.  If you notice I replaced size in a couple spots with noOfItems.  You were really close you just needed to change a couple things.

Answer (score 1):

Manually copying arrays with loops is such a pain, use [`System.arraycopy(Object,int,Object,int,int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) like

```
private int size = 0;
private Object[] store = new Object[INITIALSIZE];
private void growBufferIfNecessary() {
    if (size >= store.length) {
        Object[] newStore = new Object[2 * store.length];
        System.arraycopy(store, 0, newStore, 0, store.length);
        store = newStore;
    }
}
```

I eliminated `noOfItems`. You don't need it, your `add` method is just

```
public void add(Object obj) {
    growBufferIfNecessary();
    store[size++] = obj;
}
```

Finally, your `toString()` could use [`Arrays.copyOf(T[], int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28T[],%20int%29) like

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOf(store, size));
}
```

And then I got your expected output

```
[a, b]
[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h] 
[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i]
```